# How to resize image on Azure Functions 2.0 using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions, imageresizer

In the past I've created a azure function (in csx) to resize an image and then store it in a blob container. It was even available as a template in the portal (although now it's not available)

Yet now I'm trying to resize an image using azure functions 2.0 in visual studio and are having surprising difficulties.

System.Drawing doesn't seem to be supported or will not run on sandbox.

ImageResizer Nuget doesn't support NetCore 2.1.

MagicScaler gives the following error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'PhotoSauce.MagicScaler.Interop.Wic' threw an exception. ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: COM is not supported
```

I just need to get a stream (or byte[]) resize it and send it to a container. What is the best solution to use now in Azure Functions 2.0?

Comment: There is a sample code available on [github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/function-image-upload-resize), it uses the Function v2.

Comment: It uses ImageSharp which is still in beta... Is this the only way?

Answer (score 0):

[Imageflow.NET](https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet) is the successor to ImageResizer and works on .NET Core/.NET Standard 2.0. It produces much smaller files than the alternative compressors at higher quality, and does so faster. Disclaimer: I'm the author.